# pasive configure for apc

Tags: php, apc

APC save in memory a php file, and with one request check last modified of file for refresh.

Is possible disable this check for never check none file, and refresh the cache manually ( with a script for example) ?

Answer (score 0):

Use apc.stat=0 option to prevent APC from checking filechanges.
You'll get high performance increase on small scripts having lot of calls.

You'll have to restart httpd or call [apc-clear-cache()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apc-clear-cache.php) to reset cache. If you know a way to refresh just one page, let me know.